# How to click an element by innerthtml using CSS selectors in Selenium

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have HTML code like this

```
<td>Save</td>
```

I couldn't locate the element using FireFinder by td:contains("Save")

Is FireFinder wont support the :contains or innerHTML cant be located by :contains?

Read that in Selenium too, :contains wont be supported? However, I couldn't find a documentation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work in Selenium, I've just tried it myself. Make sure you specify that the locator type is CSS by preceding your locator with `css=`. Also, the quotes shouldn't be necessary:

```
css=td:contains(Save)
```

Comment: I am trying that in IE7. No success yet

Answer (score 0):

Firefinder does not support :contains, however Firebug has another extension called [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/). The selector type Sizzle is a javascript selector with the same syntax as CSS selectors but also supports :contains.

Also, although Firefinder does not support contains, Selenium does.